# Avoid nested loops when checking data in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, nested

I have two lists of dictionaries:

```
dict_list1 = [{'k1':1, 'k2':2}, {'k1':3, 'k2':4}]
dict_list2 = [{'k1':1, 'k2':2, 'k3':10}, {'k1':3, 'k2':4, 'k3':10}]
```

And now for each dict_x in dict_list1, I want to know if there is a dict_y on dict_list2 that contains every key,value from dict_x.

I cannot think of another way of doing this other then:

```
for dict_x in dict_list1:
    for dict_y in dict_list2:
        count = len(dict_x)
        for key, val in dict_x.items():
            if key in dict_y and dict_y[key] == val:
                count -= 1
        if count == 0:
            print('YAY')
            break
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dict` views can perform quick "is subset" testing via the inequality operators. So:

```
if dict_x.items() <= dict_y.items():  # Use .viewitems() instead of .items() on Python 2.7
```

will only return true if every key/value pair in `dict_x` also appears in `dict_y`.

This won't change anything in terms of big-O performance, but it does make the code somewhat cleaner:

```
for dict_x in dict_list1:
    for dict_y in dict_list2:
        if dict_x.items() <= dict_y.items():
            print('YAY')
            break
```

Note that creating the views costs *something* (it's just a fixed cost, not dependent on `dict` size), so if performance matters, it may be worth caching the views; doing so for `dict_list1` is free:

```
for dict_x in dict_list1:
    dict_x_view = dict_x.items()
    for dict_y in dict_list2:
        if dict_x_view <= dict_y.items():
            print('YAY')
            break
```

but some eager conversions would be needed to cache both:

```
# Convert all of dict_list2 to views up front; costs a little if
# not all views end up being tested (we always break before finishing)
# but usually saves some work at the cost of a tiny amount of memory
dict_list2_views = [x.items() for x in dict_list2]
for dict_x in dict_list1:
    dict_x_view = dict_x.items()
    for dict_y_view in dict_list2_views:
        if dict_x_view <= dict_y_view:
            print('YAY')
            break
```

You could also collapse the loop using `any` (which removes the need to `break` since `any` short-circuits), so the first (simplest) check could become:

```
for dict_x in dict_list1:
    if any(dict_x.items() <= dict_y.items() for dict_y in dict_list2):
       print('YAY')
```

This could be further collapsed to a single list comprehension that results in the various matches, but at that point the code is going to be pretty cramped/ugly:

```
for _ in (dict_x in dict_list1 if any(dict_x.items() <= dict_y.items() for dict_y in dict_list2)):
    print('YAY')
```

though without knowing what you'd really do (as opposed to just printing `YAY`) that's getting a little pointless.

Comment: Accepting @ShadowRanger answer because it is more complete.

Answer (score 3):

Below, I use the fact that the [`dict.items` view implements `set` operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) to check for each `d1.items()` if there exists a `d2.items()`, such that `d1.items()` is a subset of `d2.items()`

```
[any(d1.items() <= d2.items() for d2 in dict_list2) for d1 in dict_list1]
```

Comment: My current version returns a list the length of `dict_list1` representing whether or not some element of `dict_list2` is a superdict of the dict at that index in `dict_list1`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `any` and `all`:

```
dict_list1 = [{'k1':1, 'k2':2}, {'k1':3, 'k2':4}]
dict_list2 = [{'k1':1, 'k2':2, 'k3':10}, {'k1':3, 'k2':4, 'k3':10}]
v = [any(all(c in i and i[c] == k for c, k in b.items()) for i in dict_list2)\
   for b in dict_list1]
```

Output:

```
[True, True]
```

Comment: This only checks keys, not values.

Comment: Also, doesn't it have multiple loops just put in a 1-liner?

Comment: Yes, I supose there are 3 fors as well, but in one single line

Comment: Try `dict_list1 = [{'k1':1, 'k2': None}]` and `dict_list2 = [{'k1':1}]`.